# What will happen if I delete SAM file from windows?

Tags: windows, windows-10

I want to know if deleting SAM file will only remove the passwords or it will also create some irritating errors?

Note- I know how to delete SAM.

Answer (score 1):

The SAM file is responsible for storing the local users' passwords on a workgroup computer.

Normally, while Windows is running, it is impossible to delete the SAM file,
as it is locked to all users by the Windows Kernel.

If the SAM is somehow deleted in some way while Windows is running,
the system loses all user account passwords, resulting in Windows throwing an error
exception (Blue Screen) and shutting down.

If the SAM is deleted while Windows is not running, for example when booting
from a live Linux media, Windows is unable to load the user login screen
and will crash.

A backup copy of the SAM may be found in the folder
`C:\Windows\System32\config\RegBack`,
but you have no control and knowledge of when it was backuped.

Comment: What if i place someone's sam file in place of mine

Comment: This might work, since the SAM is just a registry database. You may also load a someone else's SAM file into `regedit` and so examine its contents without replacing yours.

Comment: If you wish to remove passwords use Credential Manager instead - much wiser than deleting registry databases.